# Access Error 2501: The OutputTo action was canceled. Running from System Account

Tags: pdf, ms-access-2010

I'm having trouble with Microsoft Access 2010.  I have a reporting module that prints reports to printer, or to file.  The reports can be user requested, or automatic print.  The user requested reports run from the desktop logged in user.  The automatic print is kicked off by my Windows Service.

We used to print these to .RTF and they work fine.  We want to modify our access reporting database to print to .PDF.  This is where the fun begins.  If we launch the access database as a user application, the report prints fine.  If we launch the access database from our windows service we get an error 2501 "The OutputTo action was canceled."

This application is running on Windows 2008 Server R2.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "Summary", acViewPreview
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Summary", acFormatPDF, DataBasePath & "Summary.pdf"
DoCmd.Close acReport, "Summary", acSaveNo
```

If I change the acFormatPDF to acFormatRTF (and change the filename to summary.rtf) this works fine.  If I run this code as a logged in user, it works fine and generates the PDF.  If I change my windows service to "run as" a user instead of the System Account, it works as well.

Unfortunately, I'm not in a position to run the service as a user account (without a LOT of testing).

Any thoughts on why the system account cannot OutputTo PDF?

Comment: Do you have any PDF 'printer' installed (e.g. an Adobe trial) other than the default provided by Office?

Comment: I know that this won't help you with your current problem, but, for the long term, I advise you to move to a different architecture. Running Office applications in an unattended (e.g. service) context is [officially not supported by Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread - but I wanted to provide a potential solution to this problem in case other users are having similar issues.

I was trying to do something very similar, and found the same thing happened for me as well. My solution was to integrate Stephen Lebans' ReportToPDF (found here: http://www.lebans.com/reporttopdf.htm) into my project, and to change my calls from

```
    DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, strReportName, acFormatPDF, strFilePath
```

to

```
    modReportToPDF.ConvertReportToPDF strReportName, , strFilePath, , False
```

After tweaking permissions on the C:\Windows\Temp folder, my service is now able print PDFs from the Local System account.

If you have not found a solution yet, you may want to consider this as an option.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was because the output was attempting to overwrite a file that was open in Adobe Acrobat, which took me a while to notice. And it later turned out that the same thing would happen if the existing file was being previewed in Windows File Explorer.