# DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPdf, ""& ".pdf", False Crashing and creating .tmp file for one user only

Tags: vba, ms-access

An access database had a table and query added. None of the code was changed. No references were added or removed. The reporting function now crashes for one user only. The code all runs fine until the end when it reaches:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "ReportNameVariable", acFormatPdf, "FileNameVariable"&".pdf", False
```

No errors are given. The database closes and an empty .tmp file is created in the destination folder. The access database works as expected for all other users. My question seems very similar to this one:

[Creating PDF file in VBA code causes Access to crash/close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50723549/creating-pdf-file-in-vba-code-causes-access-to-crash-close)

However it never was answered.

Comment: You are not passing a filename. How is that supposed to work?

Comment: Edited to represent a report name and file name being passed.

Comment: One machine out of many has issue? Does same user logged onto different machine still have issue? Reinstall Access, reconfigure machine, change user permissions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47044702/4836581 try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if the bad machine has an earlier version of Access.  I don't think the False param of DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport was available in earlier versions. Or perhaps the bad machine doesn't have an installed PDF printer? Or the user may not have rights to create/save a file in the tmp path?

Comment: This was the closest to helping me resolve the issue. The issue was there was a linked view in the access database. The view was altered and the one user did not have select permissions on some of the new schemas. The view was not directly referenced in the functionality they were using and no error was thrown. However it caused an issue when generating the pdf. When clicking on the linked view the error was given that they did not have select permission. Thank you for all of your responses.